# CSS class for a DIV

Tags: css

Am I missing something. I have the following CSS:

```
    <style = "text/css">
        .sidebar_qustions {padding: 10px; background-color: Green;}
        div.sidebar_qustions {padding: 10px;}
        DIV.sidebar_qustions {padding: 15px;}
        DIV .sidebar_qustions {padding: 20px;}
        ul.sidebar_questions_outer { list-style: none; margin: 0px; color: Red;}
        ul.sidebar_questions_inner { list-style: none; display:inline }
        li.sidebar_questions_inner { display:inline; padding: 5px; }
    </style>
```

When I have this code below then the sidebar_questions DIV doesn't get styled:

```
<div id="sidebarwrapleft">
    <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar_questions">
```

I thought I could apply a style to the div so I tried a few different ways above but none of them work. Is it possible to apply a style to a DIV.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misspelt .sidebar_questions in your css

in your css you have

```
.sidebar_qustions
```

and in your html you have

```
<div class="sidebar_questions">
```

For troubleshooting this sort of issue use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/) and its plugin [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). This will allow you to right click on the relevant part of your page and see the style being applied. If there is no style shown then this means that you either misspelt the name, or did not include the style sheet, or in this case made a mistake in defining your style sheet element.

You can look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2) for the correct WC3 recommendations as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

The style tag should look like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

Why do you write directives for the same classe over and over? Also, 'quEstions' is misspelled.

```
.sidebar_questions {padding: 10px; background-color: Green;}
div.sidebar_questions {padding: 10px;}
DIV.sidebar_questions {padding: 15px;}
DIV.sidebar_questions {padding: 20px;}
```